# How to set up QTCreator compiler

Tags: qt

I'm completely new to [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) Creator I have never ussed it before so I just installed it. Cause I need to change a little thing of this amazing program I'm ussing to graph serial data comming from an Arduino sensor:

https://os.mbed.com/users/borislav/notebook/serial-port-plotter/#commentform

Basically I'm doing an electrocardiogram and this program works perfectly but I need to change the colors cause is a standard medical thing to read the heart data in a white backround and the graph in color black.  (this program has a black backround and a red graph).

And that's basically all I need, an executable program with just that colors, so I thought I try to edit the code but  after I open this project in `QT`, it appears an error:

> 13:37:46: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
>   Error while building/deploying project prueba1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1
>   MSVC2015 32bit)

When executing step `Make`, QT Creator needs a compiler set up to build, configure a  compiler in the kit options.

How does this can be done? Step by step. Thanks so much, I'm new to this plataform.

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio ? By default Qt Creator will auto-detect the VS installation and set up its configuration appropriately. But you need MSVC2015 (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MSVC 2015 in Qt Creator you have to install it manually.
You can get from any free version:

- Visual Studio Community 2015
- Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop
- Visual C++ Build Tools 2015

Note that you can also install the MSVC 2015 compiler as part of Visual Studio 2017, but Qt Creator does not support it.

Also note that you have to install the CDB debugger manually to debug your program, it is included in the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

If you are a beginner, it might be easier to use the MinGW toolchain. You can install it directly from the Qt Maintenance Tool.